# Paperclip - How to control which characters are escaped/changed to an underscore in an uploaded filename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In a recent paperclip gem upgrade I noticed that the uploaded filenames are being modified and some characters are being changed to an underscore.

I don't not like the fact that it changes spaces to underscores. What's wrong with a space in a file name? The 90's are long over..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some digging I found this undocumented option for has_attached_file:

```
:restricted_characters
```

The default value of this option seems to be this:

```
:restricted_characters => /[&$+,\/:;=?@<>\[\]\{\}\|\\\^~%# ]/,
```

The last one is a space. Remove it and you're good.

Comment: I did exactly this and it worked perfectly. Thanks @Yoni!